# Pandas dataframe drop by column

Tags: python, pandas, drop

I want to filter a dataframe based on values in a column. Here is how the df looks:

```
    lead_snp Set_1 Set_2 Set_3 Set_4 Set_5  ... Set_4995 Set_4996 Set_4997 Set_4998 Set_4999 Set_5000
0  1:2444414     8     7     1    10    17  ...       16        6       10       12        8       12
1  1:1865298     2     2    11    21     6  ...       16        3       13       17        8        3
2  1:1865298     2     2    11    21     6  ...       16        3       13       17        8        3
3  1:1865298     2     2    11    21     6  ...       16        3       13       17        8        3
4  1:1865298     2     2    11    21     6  ...       16        3       13       17        8        3
```

When I run `(lead_chrom_only_df.groupby("lead_snp").nunique().drop("lead_snp", axis=1))`, I get the error below:

```
KeyError: "['lead_snp'] not found in axis"
```

Not sure if I'm missing something obvious, thanks in advance.

Comment: After `groupby` `"lead_snp"` is the index. `lead_chrom_only_df.groupby("lead_snp").nunique().reset_index(drop=True)` should work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try pass the `as_index = False`

```
out =  lead_chrom_only_df.groupby("lead_snp",as_index = False).nunique().drop("lead_snp", axis=1)
```